# SFTP : "Skipping non-existing key file" - should I create a key file even with username/password security?

Tags: sftp

I set up a SFTP client on our server,our client requested username/password security. (I will change it to private key security at a later stage).
Everything works, there are not setup issues and I can connect/upload/download to and from the SFTP server.

However, even with explicitly selecting Logon Type: Normal (username/password),
in FileZilla, FileZilla is still trying to first get a key file:

```
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to sftp.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx...
Status: Skipping non-existing key file "different PPK that I user elsewhere.ppk"
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command:    open "username@sftp.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 22
Command:    Trust new Hostkey: Once
Command:    Pass: ******
```

I admit I know little about SFTP security. I know we should be using a private/public key combination and we will move to that.

This initial attempted retrieval of a PPK even though the logon type is set to normal, what is this about?

I am concerned that there is something I should know, that I don't, and that I don't even know what questions I should be asking.

Comment: "* don't even know what questions I should be asking.*" ... so the question is what is the question?

Comment: This initial attempted retrieval of a PPK even though the logon type is set to normal, what is this about? Should I be concerned with this?

Comment: Even though I saved the fingerprint from the server in my FileZilla client, it still executes:  Skipping non-existing key file "different PPK that I user elsewhere.ppk" - this is what I do not understand